# Questions regarding python setup script

Tags: python, setup.py

I have a few questions regarding python setup scripts or rather how to properly setup a module (as I am doing this for the first time and kind of struggling).

For simplicity I just post a link to the corresponding github repository rather than explaining the project in detail. I am fully aware that the project as it is will not work (e.g. the file constants.py is missing) but for starters I would like the "structure" to work.

There are two main components in this project, i.e. pymap and agb - both dependent on each other (which should not be a problem I guess). I also would like to use scripts located in the bin/ directory which of course use the modules pymap and agb. For installation I use `sudo ./setup.py develop` which installs the modules as I can now use them in a python3 shell. The line `import pymap.pymap_gui` will throw an error (since constants.py is not yet in the project) however the import can be resolved.

When - on the other hand - calling the scripts with `pymap.py` the same import can not even be resolved:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymap.pymap_gui'; 'pymap' is not a package
```

How can this be even though from a python3 shell the import works perfectly fine?

Furthermore - where to improve my project structure? Is my setup the way to go (not minding the messy code and not yet working project itself - I am viewing this from kinda structure-ish perspective).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simply that the module had the same name as the script (pymap and pymap.py). Sorry for bothering!